# Generating a random permutation of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, shuffle

I am trying to make a "terminal hack" game but I am stuck at somewhere.
This is what my code currently looks:

```
import random

candidateWords = ['AETHER', 'BADGED', 'BALDER', 'BANDED', 'BANTER', 'BARBER'] #etc, etc

def wordlist():
    for index, item in enumerate(random.sample(list(candidateWords), 8)):
        print(index, ") ", item,  sep='')           
one = random.choice(candidateWords)
print(one)  

print("Welcome to the Guess-The-Word Game.\nThe Password is one of these words:")
```

I'm trying to make a list of 8 words and enumerate it to give a number for each word. Then, from the 8 words, I need to randomly choose a word to be the answer but I don't know how.

I want to use `random.sample()` and `random.choice()`.

Comment: Note: I forgot to take out the (word) from the wordlist(). Please ignore that : ) and the "one = random.choice(candidateWords) print(one)" part is totally my guess to doing what I want. It doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `random.sample()` should be <= the length of the first argument, otherwise an exception will be generated.
The rest of the code seems to be fine.

```
import random

candidateWords = ['AETHER', 'BADGED', 'BALDER', 'BANDED', 'BANTER', 'BARBER']

candidateWordsShuffled = random.sample(candidateWords, min(len(candidateWords), 8))


def wordlist():
    for index, item in enumerate(candidateWordsShuffled):
        print(index, ") ", item, sep='')

one = random.choice(candidateWordsShuffled)
print(one)

print("Welcome to the Guess-The-Word Game.\nThe Password is one of these words:")
wordlist()
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but now its seems like its only printing the one chosen word and not  the other 8 words.(because I need to print the 8 random words + the 1 chosen word out of the 8 words.)

Comment: Umm, doesn't the `wordlist()` function prints the random list?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have forgotten to paste the wordlist() at the end. but it shows the 100 words from the "candidateWords" do you know how to get just 8 words out of it?(Do I type the 8 in the for loop?

Comment: Just replace `len(candidateWords)` with `8`.

Comment: thank you, the code shows 8 words now but the random.choice is choosing a word from the original "candidateWords" list and not from the 8 words. :(

Comment: I read you new code. This is what I wanted! Thank you so much Ammol
The code shows 8 words and then picks 1 word out of it correctly.

Comment: That's great Kasey! Don't forget to give an upvote to the answer and you'll have my thanks too! :)